# Django derive model field based on other field value

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a CustomUser model

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    email    = models.EmailField(verbose_name = "email", max_length = 60, unique = True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length = 30, unique = True)
```

I am using a User creation form to register new users as follows,

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length = 60, help_text = "This will be your login.")
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ("email", "username", "password1", "password2")
```

What I want to do is remove the "username" from the form fields, so

```
fields = ("email", "password1", "password2")
```

And then when the user submits the form, I wish to insert a value into the username field based on the email provided by the user, for e.g. **email = abc@xyz.com**, *then* **username = abc**.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### form.py

```
class UserCreateForm(UserCreationForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email','first_name','last_name','password1','password2']
        exclude = ['username']

        widgets = {
            'username':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            # 'first_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            # 'last_name':forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
            'email':forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class':'form-control'}),
        }
```

#### view.py

```
def RegisterView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            fm = form.save(commit=False)
            fm.username = email.split("@")[0]
            fm.save()
            messages.success(request,f'{email} Successfully Registred')
            form = UserCreateForm()
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = UserCreateForm()
        context = {'form': form, }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

#### HTML Code

```
<form action="" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     
     {% for i in form %}
     <p>{{i.label}} {{i}}</p>
     {% endfor %}
     
     <button type="submit">Add</button>

</form>
```

#### Webpage output (register form)

[image]

#### admin panel

[image]

Comment: Many thanks @Mahammadhusain, I've tried this, but what I am stuck with, is the 2nd part where I wish to derive the username based on the email and save it to the username field in my model.

Comment: answer updated plz check it

Comment: Thanks @Mahammadhusain, I was not fully aware of how form.save(commit=False) could be used. This is perfect and that was the most important part I failed to understand. Many thanks, much appreciated.